# How to calculate $\frac{\partial\|A(I_n\otimes B)x\|^2}{\partial B}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

I am trying to calculate
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\|A(I_n\otimes B)x\|^2}{\partial B},
\end{align}
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell\times mn}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times p }$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}^{np}$.

I have expanded the 2-norm and the Kronecker and I calculated the derivatives, but I cannot recollect the terms without exploiting the block structure of $A$ and $B.$

I also tried to use $\mbox{vec}(ABC)=(C^{\rm T}\otimes A)\mbox{vec}B,\;$ but that did not work.

Is there an easy way or any helpful tricks to do this derivative?

Comment: First start with finding ***a way*** before getting greedy and asking for an easy way.  To this end, what have you tried?  What have you considered trying, if you haven't tried yet?

Comment: @amWhy I have expanded the 2-norm and the Kronecker and I calculated the derivatives, but I cannot recollect the terms without exploiting the block structure of $A$ and $B$. I also tried to use $\mbox{vec}(ABC)=(C^{\rm T}\otimes A)\mbox{vec}B$, but that did not work

Comment: That's exactly what we'd like you to include in your question.  It helps us to know what your tried, and if there is an easier way.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: Let $x={\rm vec}(X),\,\,b={\rm vec}(B)\,$ and note that $$(I_n\otimes B)x = {\rm vec}(BX) = (X^T\otimes I_m)b$$This "trick" will get you past your roadblock.

Comment: @greg Thanks. Then we can use $\frac{\partial }{\partial B}={\rm vec}^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial ({\rm vec~}B)}\right)$. Right?

Comment: @Mohkam7 Yes, that is correct.